# AssemblyScript Contracts with Javascript Standard Library

Tags: wasm, contracts, no-std

I am trying to implement a non-Rust contract using WASM.. Can anyone provide an example, please, of a small contract which returns the balance of an account, completely written in TypeScript / AssemblyScript and made to run as a smart contract on Substrate?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [ask!](https://github.com/ask-lang/ask), which is a domain-specific language for Assembly Script that enables you writing contracts for Substrate's smart contract module ‒ the [`pallet-contracts`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts).

The ask! repository contains a number of examples [here](https://github.com/ask-lang/ask/tree/main/examples), they should give you a starting point of what you're searching for.